# A property of a surjective linear transformation, to do with preserving sets of generators, preserving independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, hamel-basis

I have a scenario, and I am wondering if property $(2)$ below is necessarily true.
Is it true?

Let $V$ and $W$ be non-zero vector spaces, and $T$ be a surjective linear transformation of $V$ onto $W$. Assume that property $(1)$ holds:

> for any subset $S$ of $V$, we have that   **"$TS$ spans $W$"** implies **"$S$ spans $V$".**

Note that because $T$ is onto, the converse $(1)^C$ holds:

> for any subset $S$ of $V$, we have that   **"$S$ spans $V$"** implies **"$TS$ spans $W$".**

Now suppose we also have a finite-dimensional non-zero subspace $Z$ of $V$, and its non-zero image $TZ$ in $W$. Given all this, the uncertain property $(2)$ is

> for any subset $Y$ of $Z$, we have that   **"$TY$ spans $TZ$"** implies **"$Y$ spans $Z$".**

I tried to prove this as follows. Assume $TY$ spans $TZ$.  Then $TY \,\cup\,(W - TZ)$ spans $W$. Each of the following spans $W$ also:

$$TY \,\cup\,(TV - TZ),$$

$$TY \,\cup\,(T(V - Z)),$$

$$T(Y \,\cup\, (V - Z)).$$

Then applying $(1)$, we find that $Y \,\cup\, (V - Z)$ spans $V$.

But why should this mean that $Y$ spans $Z$? I do not see that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property (1) together with $T$ surjective implies that $T$ is an isomorphism.

Indeed, for every subset $S$ of $V$ it is true that $TS$ linearly independent implies $S$ linearly independent (no condition of surjectivity of $T$ is necessary here).<sup>1</sup>

So take a basis of $W$; since $T$ is surjective, this basis has the form $TS$ for some subset $S$ of $V$. Now, by property (1), we know that $S$ spans $V$. Since it is linearly independent, it is a basis.

Since $T$ maps a basis to a basis, it is an isomorphism.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>  For whom is not used to “lists of elements” rather than “sets of elements”, the statement should be interpreted as: assume $S'$ is a set of elements in the range of $T$ $W$ and choose, for every $w\in S'$ a vector $v\in V$ with $Tv=w$; form the set $S$ of such elements. Then $S'$ linearly independent implies $S$ linearly independent.

Comment: thanks, that is helpful; my true goal here is to show that T is an isomorphism onto W. However, I am not yet a believer in your claim, the one that begins with "Indeed,"

Comment: i doubt this claim because I see here a simple counter example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414210/is-the-image-ts-of-a-linearly-dependent-set-s-under-a-linear-transformatio/2416536#2416536

Comment: perhaps you are making some additional assumption to prove the "Indeed" claim??

Comment: @311411 No, why? Suppose $a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$, for $v_1,\dots,v_n\in S$; then $a_1T(v_1)+\dots+a_nT(v_n)=0$, forcing $a_1=\dots=a_n=0$.

Comment: i think the trouble is that we have different definitions of "a set". You are assuming that set S has n elements, which is fine. But there is no reason for set TS to have n elements. In fact TS could have only one element, a non-zero one. What then?

Comment: @311411 If you're worried about that, assume $S'$ is a set in $W$ and for every $w\in S'$ choose $v\in V$ such that $Tv=w$ and form the set $S$ of such elements. Then you should be satisfied.

Comment: @311411 I added the footnote about your issue.

Comment: thanks egreg, i think your footnote bit is just the remedy i needed!